# Ошибка - ORA-65096: invalid common user or role name - при создании пользователя

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle12c

Только установил Oracle БД и заметил, что не хватает стандартного пользователя для примеров Scott. Пытаюсь создать его самостоятельно:

```
$ sqlplus / as sysdba

SQL> create user scott identified by tiger;
```

Но получаю ошибку:

> ORA-65096: invalid common user or role name

Разве нельзя создать пользователя с именем Scott? Как быть в этом случае?

---

<sub>Свободный перевод вопроса [error: ORA-65096: invalid common user or role name in oracle](https://stackoverflow.com/q/33330968) от участника [@enu](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4359988/enu)</sub>

Comment: ассоциация:https://stackoverflow.com/q/33330968/6571020

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Без указания конкретной службы с `@service_name` вход для пользователя SYS будет всегда осуществлён в корневую (или контейнер) инстанцию БД:

```sql
$ sqlplus / as sysdba
SQL> show con_name

CON_NAME
------------------------------
CDB$ROOT
```

Это ещё не БД в привычном понимании этого термина, говоря простым языком, это её "внешняя оболочка". В ней обычно нет никакой необходимости создавать дополнительных пользователей. А если всё-таки такая необходимость появится, то создать пользователя можно только с префиксом `C##`.

```sql
SQL> create user c##scott identified by tiger;

User created.
```

Но если всё таки необходимо имя Scott, так как все готовые примеры ориентируются на это имя, то просто перейдите в ту инстанцию БД, в которой обычно работаете:

```
SQL> alter session set container=pdb1;

Session altered.

SQL> create user scott identified by tiger;

User created.
```

Подробнее о разнице между [общими и локально созданными пользователями](http://docs.oracle.com/database/121/CNCPT/cdblogic.htm#CNCPT89257).

---

Решение с изменением скрытого и недокументированного параметра:

```
alter session set "_ORACLE_SCRIPT"=true;
```

как, например, в [этом ответе](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41490385/6571020) **настоятельно не рекомендуется**.
Изменять параметры начинающиеся со знака `_` (подчёркивание) в продуктивной БД допустимо только, если в ответ на обращение в службу поддержки Oracle будет предложено такое решение.